# How to move a DialogFragment out of the center?

Tags: android, fragment, dialogfragment

Is it possible by  using a `DialogFragment` to be able to move it out of the center and place it anywhere on the screen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have success using

```
 Window window = dialog.getWindow();
 WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
 lp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT;
 lp.x = 100;
 lp.y = 100;
 window.setAttributes(lp);
```

puts my dialog in the Top Right slightly down from the corner. this code is in `onCreateDialog()`.

Answer (score 8):

You can use

`getDialog().getWindow().setAttributes(param);`

in

```
onCreateView()
```

like this

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    getDialog().getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.TOP);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams param = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes();
    param.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    param.softInputMode = WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE;
    param.x = 100;
    param.y = 100;
   .
   .
    getDialog().getWindow().setAttributes(p);
   .
   .
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suffered a lot trying all the programmatically solutions with no results. Finally I've done it from the XML file without any extra code within the Java class.

**All I've done is** Make the parent height `match_parent` and set a `gravity` for it with value `center`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
<!--The following two lines-->
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity=“center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/hide"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/cancel"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />
```